# Load .php page into a div Ajax and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

(I am pretty new to all this.) I have a page where the user can click between different sorting methods of user posts. Depending on which they click the content shown will correspond.

```
function newContent()
{
  $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/newcontent.php',
      success: function() 
      {
            $("#content_div").empty().load("ajax/newcontent.php");
      }

      });
}
```

This is what I have now. But instead of loading the code from the .php page into the #content_box, the #content_box just goes blank.

Any help would be awesome!

EDIT ** changed #content_dov to #content_div - whoops

Comment: you should give parameter to success function like success: function(msg) 
      {
            $("#content_dov").empty().html(msg);
      }

Comment: [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load) is shorthand for an entirely new ajax request. It automatically overwrites the contents of it's target, so you don't need to call empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using two ajax requests? You just need to use

```
$("#content_dov").load("ajax/newcontent.php");
```

The full code is

```
function newContent()
{
    $("#content_dov").load("ajax/newcontent.php");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function newContent()
{
  $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/newcontent.php',
      success: function(data) 
      {
            $("#content_dov").html(data);
      }

      });
}
```

Comment: Both answers worked, but @Joyce Babu answer came first. Thanks!